# how to code for getting value from one table to another on click login

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to code for getting value from registration table to the user table when the user click on login button using the phone number.
My table name is registeration, user.The registeration table have values like firstname,lastname,password,email,phone.The user table also has the same attribute.

**DatabaseHelper.java :**

```
     package com.example.lenovo.myapplication1;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME="register.db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="registeration";
        public static final String COL_1="ID";
        public static final String COL_2="FirstName";
        public static final String COL_3="LastName";
        public static final String COL_4="Password";
        public static final String COL_5="Email";
        public static final String COL_6="Phone";

        public static final String TABLE_LOGIN="login";
        public static final String COLN_1="Phone";
        public static final String COLN_2="Password";

        public static final String TABLE_USER_LOG="user";
        public static final String COLUMN_1="ID";
        public static final String COLUMN_2="FirstName";
        public static final String COLUMN_3="LastName";
        public static final String COLUMN_4="Password";
        public static final String COLUMN_5="Email";
        public static final String COLUMN_6="Phone";





        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,FirstName TEXT,LastName TEXT,Password TEXT,Email TEXT,Phone TEXT)");
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + " (Phone TEXT,Password TEXT)");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER_LOG + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,FirstName TEXT,LastName TEXT,Password TEXT,Email TEXT,Phone TEXT)");

            //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +TABLE_NAME); //Drop older table if exists
            //onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

**Register.java :**

```
package com.example.lenovo.myapplication1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button _btnreg,_btnlogin;
    EditText _txtfname,_txtlname,_txtpass,_txtemail,_txtphone;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        _btnreg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
        _txtfname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtfname);
        _txtlname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlname);
        _txtpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpass);
        _txtemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        _txtphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
        _btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

        _btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                String fname=_txtfname.getText().toString();
                String lname=_txtlname.getText().toString();
                String pass=_txtpass.getText().toString();
                String email=_txtemail.getText().toString();
                String phone=_txtphone.getText().toString();
                insertdata(fname,lname,pass,email,phone);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "register successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        _btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this,Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void insert data(String first name, String last name, String pass, String email, String phone){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2, fname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_3, lname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4, pass);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_5, email);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_6, phone);

        long id = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    }
}
```

**Login.java :**

```
package com.example.lenovo.myapplication1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.lenovo.myapplication1.DatabaseHelper.COLN_1;
import static com.example.lenovo.myapplication1.DatabaseHelper.COL_6;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    Button _btnLogin;
    EditText _txtphone,_txtpass;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        _btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        _txtphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
        _txtpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpass);

        _btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phone = _txtphone.getText().toString();
                String pass = _txtpass.getText().toString();
                insertdata(phone,pass);
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_6 + "+? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "=?", new String[]{phone,pass});
                if(cursor!=null){
                    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfuliy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //if(COL_6==COLN_1){
                  //  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + );

                //}

            }
        });
    }
    public void insertdata(String phone, String pass){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLN_1, phone);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLN_2, pass);

        long id = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOGIN, null, contentValues);

    }
}
```

Comment: its hard to understand your problem cause you can use one table for both register and login. why your using 2 different tables? Just try to store the values in user table when user register and retrieve details for validation when user Login

Comment: No i want that value in other table

Comment: I want to copy register table data to user table. plzzz help